# LinAlgError Singular Matrix error for logistic regression

Tags: logistic-regression, statsmodels

I'm getting a "numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix" error when fitting a logistic regression model.

I know its coming from feature X which is 0 for all samples and when I'm looking at `X_train.corr()` its NAN.

**I can't exclude this feature** and I'm using statsmodels because I need `cov_params()` which sklearn does not have (which is why I cant uses `method = bfgs` also)

Correlation matrix:
[image: corr matrix]

[image]

Comment: Why can't you exclude that feature? You already know it is zero, and this cannot add any additional information to your model (the feature does not vary, so nothing to learn).

Comment: because the model will train every day and this feature will change with time.

Comment: Can you try `model.fit(method="newton", ridge_factor=1e-4)`? I'm not sure this works.

Comment: That will not work because `ridge_factor` is only used during optimization but not for final hessian and cov_params.

Comment: Then what I suggest is to dynamically drop the feature only in days when it is not available (i.e. when it is all zero or has constant value)